# Dropping a release from (public) Maven Central

Tags: maven, sonatype, maven-central

A while ago I released a new maven package, accidentally adding my employer company as `<organization>` into `pom.xml`. I've been asked to replace these packages if possible.

Staging releases can be dropped. Documentation does not mention any process for taking down releases. Before I submit a support ticket, is there an official way to do this? Is it even possible?

Comment: The simple policy is that you cannot do that, see http://central.sonatype.org/articles/2014/Feb/06/can-i-change-a-component-on-central/.

Comment: Thank you, I really never hit that page!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maven Central is treated as immutable, and thus, this is not possible. This is done in case someone has begun to rely on your package. A great real life example of why this is important is the removal of leftpad from npmjs.